# Merge two dataframe based on column which has splitted value

Tags: pandas, join, merge

I have two data frames. One of the data frames appears to be as follows:
[image: Dataframe 1].

Products columns contain data like 1;3;5.

**The other data frame looks like:**

[image]

I am merging both of the frames:

```
Merge_Store_Transaction['products'] = Merge_Store_Transaction['products'].str.split(';')
Merge_Store_Transaction = Merge_Store_Transaction.explode('products')
```

Which give me result like: It duplicated all other values that I don't want. Is there a way where it divide the **profit column** with respective number of products and replicate the number or just fill other rows with zero.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that once you have this result, you can do something like the following:

```
Merge_Store_Transaction["profit"] = Merge_Store_Transaction.groupby(["group_id", "date"])["profit"].mean().reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

Same thing for the `revenue_in_usd` column.

Comment: It gives me an error 
 ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels